# Unable to read the entire file correctly using fseek() and fread()

Tags: c++, fread, fseek

I have a file with shader source which i want to read that looks like this:

```cpp
#version 460 core
layout(location = 0) in vec2 pos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 color;
layout(location = 0) out vec3 fragColor;

uniform float rand;
out gl_PerVertex
{
  vec4 gl_Position;
  float gl_PointSize;
  float gl_ClipDistance[];
};

void main()
{
    fragColor = color * rand;
    gl_Position = vec4(pos.x + 0.5 * gl_InstanceID, pos.y, 0, 1);
}
```

first i find out the size of my file:

```cpp
fseek(m_file, 0L, SEEK_END);
size_t size = ftell(m_file);
```

This returns 364. The problem is that if i just copy+paste the file content into a `R"()"` string and get a strlen it returns 347.
After getting file size i try reading the whole file:

```cpp
fseek(m_file, 0, SEEK_SET);
size_t count = fread(buffer, 1, size, m_file);
```

where `buffer` is allocated with 364 bytes. But fread returns 347 and feof(m_file) returns true. So as a result i get this:
[image: buffer content after reading a file with fread]

(File explorer also shows that the file size is 364).

However, when i read the same file into a string using `std::ifstream`, everything works properly:

```cpp
std::ifstream ifs(filename);
std::string content((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)),
    (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
auto size = content.size();
```

and `size` is equal to 347.

[image: string content after reading a file with std::ifstream]

The question is: am i doing something wrong or Windows/fseek just show the file size wrongly?

Comment: Do you open the file in binary mode in the C code? Does the file have Windows or POSIX line endings (`\r\n` versus `\n`)?

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil well this is a question about a subset of C++ which exists both in C and C++. The C++ STL example was only added to show the difference in their work.

Comment: @DanyloSadivnychyi: Even if something is common to both C and C++, it should not be tagged with both. Guidance for these tags is generally to avoid using both except when asking about differences or interactions between the languages. Applying both tags consumes the time of people who have chosen to follow the C tag but not the C++ tag, and you should respect the value of other people’s time and their choices. Overlapping tags also results in problems like people searching for a C solution and finding this question, which currently has only a C++ answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the two sizes is 19 which coincidencally is the number of lines in your shader.

My guess is this has something to do with line ending conversations. Open the file as binary and the discrepency should go away.

Comment: Indeed, i added the "b" to file open mode and this helped. Thanks